# Wrong datetime - PHP+ SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, locale

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); 
//output: 13/12/2012 11:10:57

print_r(getDataArray($dblink, 'select current_timestamp')); 
//output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [computed] => **2012-04-12 11110:05** ) )
```

When I try to get a "current_timestamp" + php + sql server, I get an error, an incorrect date. Can anyone help me?

- date convert in mssql config (php.ini) is "off"

that's a problem in locale.conf ? /etc/locale.conf ....

thanks

Comment: Is mssql  installed on same server where PHP is running? (How did you install Microsoft SQL server on CentOS?)

Comment: @BogdanBurim no.. another server. (i use mssql - php 5.2.10)

Comment: You need to check those server settings (locale, date and time)

Comment: The SQL Server is configured correctly. The problem only happens when I use php + mssql. When I run a query ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be with the format that datetime columns are returned in.

Try this in  your php.ini :

After this line:

```
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On
```

Add this line:

```
mssql.datetimeconvert = Off
```

Comment: I've changed this parameter to "off" .. didn't work anyway. very strange :/

Comment: This sounds similar to your problem.. http://blog.kotowicz.net/2009/09/weird-date-format-from-freetds-with.html

Answer (score -1):

Try:

After connection execute query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```

PHP:

```
odbc_exec($conn, "SET DATEFORMAT ymd");
```